# how we display the value form database in spacific span or div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am trying to check my value form database it already enter or not before submitting the form
i have code its display the result in text box how it is possible that result is display in div or span.
my code is as under:
my first file category.php have script and html form

script

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#id").keyup(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "dbscript2.php",
                data : "id=" + $("#id").val(),
                success : function(html) {

                    $("#message").val(html);

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

html form is :

```
 <form method="POST" action="gcd.php">
    <p>
        <label>Category:</label>
        <input type="text" name="category" id="id" tabindex="1" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <div id="mes"></div>
        <input type="text" name="new" id="message" tabindex="2" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</form>
```

and last php file message dbscript2.php

```
<?php
    include "config.php";
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $q=mysql_query("select * from category where category   ='$id'");
    $num=mysql_num_rows($q);
    if($num==0)
        echo "";
    else
    {
        echo "This Category already Entered";
    }
?>
```

Comment: **Side-note** Watch out for SQL-injections!

Comment: forget about data from database, how do you display it in the case of static data?

Comment: i only want to display the message that this category are submitted already or not so dbscript2.php check this and return the message

Comment: thanks prash first i learn how write the data in div. and then i get the answer problem is solved so i use $("#mes").append("<div>" + html + "</div>");

Comment: your `mes` is already a `div`, why do you want to append again `div` unless really required? please see my post below

Answer (score 0):

Since there are couple of errors in the actual code you shared and the answer you derived, let me put it across here

HTML form

```
<form method="POST" action="gcd.php">
    <p>
        <label>Category:</label>
        <input type="text" name="id" id="id" tabindex="1" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <div id="mes"></div>
        <input type="text" name="message" id="message" tabindex="2" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</form>
```

The core code where you want the data to get inserted to the div

```
$("#mes").text(html);
```

Please note that you get the value returned from the php script, and not some html. Hence it is better to rename your expected return value as some other identifier say mydata

```
 $("#mes").text(mydata);
```

Please let me know if you are looking for something else.

**Updated** based on OP's further query

Please read jquery API docs, It gives you an idea of the supported functions http://api.jquery.com/.

To your specific question, yes you can hide or show a particular div using the below calls:

//check your condition and show or hide the div accordingly

```
$("#mydiv").show();
```

or

```
$("#mydiv").hide();
```

Comment: i understand ,append insert new div at every entry. i am wrong . thanks prash its very helpful and learning with you.

Comment: another question can we disable and visible the div on the basses of our return value as in our case  '  mydata  '  for example if(mydata) have some text then div show else div not show

Comment: Glad to hear, thanks. But I would suggest you to learn from the API docs. Also dont ask completely new questions on an existing question thread. Anyways I have updated , please see the updated post. Please feel free to accept as answer if that helped.

Comment: its just a suggestion.. you can accept the answer and close the thread. lol :)